# Servicio en Windows C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, servicio

Cree un servicio el cual debe de guardar un archivo en una ruta pero me esta diciendo que no tiene acceso a la ruta.
EL servicio se instala con la siguiente configuracion:

```html
// serviceProcessInstaller1
            // 
            this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
            this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Password = null;
            this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = null;
```

Puse un log y me regresa lo siguiente:

```html
5/7/2021 2:47:55 PM Access to the path '\\server\carpeta1\subcarpeta\doc.pdf' is denied.
```

Como puedo instalarlo y que tenga todos los privilegios?

Comment: No es común darle a los servicios privilegios sobre la red y obviamente el usuario del sistema local no va a tener acceso a una ruta que no lo es. Con el servicio ya instalado puedes editar las propiedades del servicio y cambiar, en la pestaña _"logon"_ el usuario bajo el que corre y hacerlo con un usuario que tenga permisos en la red.

Comment: Tengo un usuario administrador lo puse y funciona correctamente desde mi equipo, ahora lo provare en el servidor y creo deberia de funcionar igualmente ya que ahi es donde estara instalado.

Comment: @jachguate lo instale en el server pero ahora me sale otro error solo en el server, localmente en mi PC funciona correctamente. El error dice: La solicitud falló. No se puede conectar con el servidor remoto

Comment: ¿Qué operación es la que falla exactamente?

Answer (score 0):

Primero intenta ejecutar tu programa como administrador

1. click derecho en el programa (o al IDE si lo corres desde ahí)
2. ejecutar como administrador

Si esto no resuelve el problema intenta cambiar las propiedades de la carpeta

1. click derecho en la carpeta
2. propiedades
3. pestaña seguridad
4. Editar
5. Agregar
6. lo mas fácil es agregar todo los usuarios tecleando "Everyone" (si tienes windows 10 en español, en la última actualización aparece como "Todos")
7. Aceptar
8. Selecciona el usuario
9. Click Checkbox "Control total"
10. Aceptar.

Espero te sirva, saludos.